# Django: pre_save & request

Tags: django, model

I have a pre_save function and want to get the session_id with session_order_id = request.session['order_id’]

The problem I am currently facing is that I am always getting the error name 'request' is not defined. Does anyone know how I can fix that? Or is it possible to pass this variable form my views.py as a kwarg? (I just couldn’t figure out how.)

```
class TransactionProfile(models.Model):
    [...]

def transaction_profile_pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    session_order_id = request.session['order_id’]
    o = Order.objects.get(order_id=session_order_id)
    o.transaction_profile = instance
```

Marc

Comment: There is no `request` in signals. Signals have model instances & database related elements, the request is only available where your views are concerned (where a user is actually making a request).

Comment: Django's HTTP response/request workflow and ORM are completely separate and there is no notion of `request` as far as ORM is concerned. You can consider implementing a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/) depending on your use case.